# Is FIDE president Kirsan Ilyumzhinov a good chess player? What's his Elo rating?

Tags: rating, elo, fide, famous-players

On this page it says he is not rated: http://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=34123811

I could only find one game featuring Ilyumzhinov, in which he played a 2300 Elo player and lost: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1600034

That's not very impressive for someone who owns FIDE and who boasts of having played a few games with aliens...

Comment: Games with aliens? Lol! Any source for this?

Comment: does sepp batter know how to kick a ball? can bernie ecclestone drive a f1 car?

Comment: The FIDE president needs to be a politician, bureaucrat, lobbyist, and chess enthusiast.  He does not have to be a master-level player.

Comment: @Wes He doesn't claim to have played games with aliens, but he does claim to have been abducted by them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCmHi50Mve0

Comment: @TonyEnnis, that makes Kasparov an even better candidate, doesn't it?

Comment: @Wes It could well indeed. Assuming he can actually get along with people and bring consensus.

Comment: @Wes I believe that kasparov ran for it, he usually criticize the president as I recall. Anyway kirsan has more money, which is what you need to be a president, see my previous comment, besides  kasparov is keeping busy with russian politics stuff.

Comment: Note that he is a __president__. - He does not own FIDE. Same is with other associations. First that comes to mind is Euroleague. Jordi Bertomeu Orteu, the president of the Euroleague, is not a basketball player! Furthermore, he may not be a president soon - someone else may be elected.

Answer (score 2):

Little is known about his rating, indeed, he has no FIDE rating.

I dug deeper in the tournament that [lodebari found](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/12422/672), at [the FIDE page for the  2012 Members Appreciation Blitz tournament](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_report.phtml?event16=68859&t=2). Apparently he scored 2.5/7 against a 1950 Elo average, beating a 1850 and a 1700, losing to two 1900s and some stronger players, and drawing to a 1670.

That doesn't look like a 2300-rated player to me. **More like 1850.**

Comment: With the benefit of time, I'll add that typically 2300-rated players would usually play a fair number of tournaments, maybe some international ones, and definitely have a FIDE rating. So the loud absence of all these things is much more indicative of, yeah, some sub-2000 strength.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source provided by @Lynob, Kirsan Ilyumzhinov had a rating of 2300 and was local champion of Kalmykia at the age of 14 (see also [here](http://russiapedia.rt.com/prominent-russians/politics-and-society/kirsan-ilyumzhinov/)). The game you mention against Alexander Zakharov took place in 1978, when Ilyumzhinov was about 16 years old.

However, and as you say, Kirsan Ilyumzhinov is unrated at the moment according to FIDE. But according to the same [source](https://ratings.fide.com/chess_statistics.phtml?event=34123811&details=1) he has played 9 rated games (not enough to get a rating). Making some research I found he played these games in the [Members Appreciation Blitz](http://chess-db.com/public/tournament.jsp?id=68859) Tournament in Skokie (USA) in 2012 with a result of +4 =1 -4.

Appart from that, I think he mostly plays friendly games. If you search "Kirsan Ilyumzhinov plays chess" in Google you'll find some images of him playing with different people, such as Gaddafi, Steven Seagal, the Minister of Sports Affairs of Oman or a Paraguayan student.

Comment: Digging deeper in that tourney you unveil, at https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_report.phtml?event16=68859&t=2 : apparently he scored 2.5/7 against a 1950 Elo average, beating a 1850 and a 1700, losing to two 1900s, and drawing a 1650. Doesn't look like a 2300-strong player to me. **More like 1850.**

Answer (score -2):

He has a rating of 2300

> As a competitor, he had a FIDE rating of 2300, just shy of earning the
>   title chess master.

Source [Al Jazeera report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL344FF489D4620047&feature=player_detailpage&v=AqrsmLxkt3Y#t=584)

Comment: He is unrated according to the FIDE site. FIDE ratings don't expire, you just get a flag of inactivity if you don't play any rated games. For example according to the FIDE site Kasparov is still rated 2812 at standard despite not having played any FIDE rated games since April 2005 - https://ratings.fide.com/hist.phtml?event=4100018 .

Comment: @BrianTowers firstly, we don't downvote an answer on SE just because we disagree with the answer, we downvote an answer if it's a bad answer and clearly, I have reference which make my answer valid, in fact I saw that link before posting my answer 4 months ago and didn't consider posting it, there has to be an answer, no rating is not the answer I'm looking for, nor the the answer that the OP wants to know, he already know that. I stand by my answer, the reporter clearly know better, having met him personally

Comment: @BrianTowers as for why it's not showing on the site, I don't know and don't care